# ¿Cómo pausar un video al cerrar una modal y reproducirlo automáticamente con Bootstrap 4?

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap, bootstrap-4, modal

espero me puedan ayudar!
Tengo el siguiente modal:

> 

```
 <div class="modal fade " id="videoModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="videoModalLabel"
    aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title font-weight-bold" id="videoModalLabel" style="color: #3c0074;">Maestría en Educación y
            Docencia online</h5>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body text-center">
          <div class="iframe-container embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9 embed-container">
            <iframe id="video" class="embed-responsive-item" src="./assets/img/maestria/Video/bienvenida.m4v"
              title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0"
              allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture"
              allowfullscreen></iframe>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

La linea que abre el modal dice #videoModal

Pero me doy cuenta que al abrir el modal no reproduce automáticamente el video, y al cerrar la modal lo sigue reproduciendo. Quiero que haga lo contrario, al abrir la modal reproduzca el video automáticamente y al cerrarlo que el video pare.

Comment: Si está usando youtube, debe usar la api de youtube para programar esos controles, si está usando un video propio, debe hacerlo con la API de Video de HTML5 .

Comment: Va a ser muy complicado que puedas controlar el video estando dentro de un `iframe`. ¿Por qué no lo pones con una etiqueta `video`?

Answer (score 1):

gracias por sus comentarios. Ya pude resolverlo!  quedo de la siguiente manera:

```
 <script>
    $('#videoModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (event) {
      $('#videoFrame').attr('src', './assets/img/maestria/Video/bienvenida.m4v');
    });
    $('#videoModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (event) {
      $('#videoFrame').removeAttr('src', null);
    });
  </script>
```